# The whole idea behind one ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

What is the whole idea behind One Asp? Is it something like we will be able to develop applications for all asp.net framework without any target framework oriented development using VS IDE. How it can change the usage of ASP.NET in the future?

Comment: @boj Please don't use code formatting to simply highlight keywords. It is only for actual code.

Comment: Your question is off topic, but.. The idea of ASP.NET is to create dynamic web-pages. What else does it need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net is a framework. means simply it is a collection of large library to solve different programming needs when a programmer wants to write a software. A library is not of books but of small different collection of code . ASP.net is a .net framework. means one who knows ASP programming then ASP.NET is an extention of ASP in .net framework.

It is mainly used for:

***Improved Performance and Scalability***

***Enhanced Reliability***

***Easy Deployment***

***New Application Models***

***Developer Productivity***